# Why is the relation between euclidean and hyperbolic length defined as such?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

Let us define the hyperbolic plane to be the set $\mathbb{H^2} = \{x \in \mathbb{R^2} \mid |x| < 1 \} = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R^2} \mid x^2 + y^2 < 1\}$

In my textbook it states that in the hyperbolic plane, hyperbolic length and area are measured infinitesimally in terms of euclidean length and area by

$d_H L = \frac{2}{1 - |x|^2} d_E L$

$d_H A = \frac{4}{(1 - |x|^2)^2} d_E A$

Can anybody explain why this is? No explanation was provided in my textbook.

Comment: If I remember correctly, if you take a sphere and then take a stereographic projection onto a plane, and transport the Riemannian metric from the sphere onto the plane, what you get with appropriate parameters is a Riemannian metric $\langle v_1, v_2 \rangle' = \frac{1}{1 + |x|^2} \langle v_1, v_2 \rangle$ in terms of the plane's Riemannian metric $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$.  So, given that formula for a metric with constant positive curvature, you might guess a metric with constant negative curvature would be as given.  (Not confident enough in this to write an answer though.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of the unit disk as covered with sticky stuff that's harder and harder to walk through the nearer you are to the boundary. In fact as you approach the boundary along a radius walking at what seems to you a steady pace, expending constant effort, you are in fact covering distance at a slower and slower rate. You can never get to the boundary.

If you want to walk from one interior point to another, the fastest route starts out taking you toward the center for a while, and then back. In fact it's a circle through those two points that is perpendicular to the boundary. Those are the "straight lines" in this model of hyperbolic geometry.

Here's a picture from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model

[image]

Instead of thinking about moving more slowly near the edge, you can think of moving at a constant rate while distances are expanding.
The differential for the hyperbolic length in terms of the Euclidean length quantifies just how sticky the stuff is, so how the distance expands.  The slowdown factor is inversely proportional to the distance from the boundary: $2/(1-|x|^2)$.

Comment: Thanks for the intuitive layman explanation. Would you know of a way to mathematically show this without too much work?

Comment: The additional question in your comment here might be a good candidate for a asking a new question, *if* you can make the question more specific and not just *Would you know of a way...". However, burying additional questions in comments to answers is a bad use of this site; the only person besides hou who will ever see such a question is the answerer and the oddball intrepid stackexchange explorer such as me.